# Deploying JRuby war file to Tomcat in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tomcat, jruby, warbler

I have a JRuby on Rails application I am trying to deploy to an existing Tomcat 7 installation with a war file created by warbler. When I drop the war file in the webapps directory it creates a directory with the war contents. I am able to access the static html (public) files however I am not able to access any of the dynamic ruby generated urls and get a 404 response.

My guess is that Tomcat doesn't know how to execute or handle the ruby files. Is there something I need to do to tell Tomcat to execute those as scripts?

In my catalina log file I see the following:

> INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache
>   Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myapp.war Mar 22, 2012 10:50:41
>   PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig webConfig SEVERE: Unable
>   to determine URL for WEB-INF/classes
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not
>   found     at
>   org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.listBindings(BaseDirContext.java:733)
>     at
>   org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.listBindings(ProxyDirContext.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1197)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:825)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:873)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Mar 22, 2012 10:50:43 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI:
>   urn:org.jruby.rack is already defined

Answer (score 0):

probably something with your paths or JRuby. See this http://www.digitalsanctum.com/2007/07/24/jruby-deploying-a-rails-application-on-tomcat/ site.